# Any problem using nested switch statement too many?

Tags: java, android-spinner

I never used nested switch statement. Just wanted to know using nested switch statement is good in my code or not.
I got 3 integer variables. **type** and **position** values `0` or `1` on both and **item** with `0` to `6`.
My code is too lengthy of this, anyway to shorten this:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long id) {
        type = spinner_type.getSelectedItemPosition();
        position = spinner_pos.getSelectedItemPosition();
        item = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
        switch (adapterView.getId()) {
            case R.id.cck_spinner_type:
                switch (pos) {
                    case 0:
                        if(position == 0 && item == 0) {
                            sp_name = "cc_left";
                        } else if(position == 0 && item == 1){
                            sp_name = "cc_left1";
                        } else if(position == 0 && item == 2){
                            sp_name = "cc_left2";
                        }else if(position == 0 && item == 3){
                            sp_name = "cc_left3";
                        }else if(position == 0 && item == 4){
                            sp_name = "cc_left4";
                        }else if(position == 0 && item == 5){
                            sp_name = "cc_left5";
                        }else if(position == 0 && item == 6){
                            sp_name = "cc_left6";
                        }else if(position == 1 && item == 0) {
                            sp_name = "cc_right";
                        } else if(position == 1 && item == 1){
                            sp_name = "cc_right1";
                        } else if(position == 1 && item == 2){
                            sp_name = "cc_right2";
                        }else if(position == 1 && item == 3){
                            sp_name = "cc_right3";
                        }else if(position == 1 && item == 4){
                            sp_name = "cc_right4";
                        }else if(position == 1 && item == 5){
                            sp_name = "cc_right5";
                        }else if(position == 1 && item == 6){
                            sp_name = "cc_right6";
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        if(position == 0 && item == 0) {
                            sp_name = "ccL_left";
                        } else if(position == 0 && item == 1){
                            sp_name = "ccL_left1";
                        } else if(position == 0 && item == 2){
                            sp_name = "ccL_left2";
                        }else if(position == 0 && item == 3){
                            sp_name = "ccL_left3";
                        }else if(position == 0 && item == 4){
                            sp_name = "ccL_left4";
                        }else if(position == 0 && item == 5){
                            sp_name = "ccL_left5";
                        }else if(position == 0 && item == 6){
                            sp_name = "ccL_left6";
                        }else if(position == 1 && item == 0) {
                            sp_name = "ccL_right";
                        } else if(position == 1 && item == 1){
                            sp_name = "ccL_right1";
                        } else if(position == 1 && item == 2){
                            sp_name = "ccL_right2";
                        }else if(position == 1 && item == 3){
                            sp_name = "ccL_right3";
                        }else if(position == 1 && item == 4){
                            sp_name = "ccL_right4";
                        }else if(position == 1 && item == 5){
                            sp_name = "ccL_right5";
                        }else if(position == 1 && item == 6){
                            sp_name = "ccL_right6";
                        }
                        break;
                }
                break;

            case R.id.cck_spinner_pos:
                switch (pos) {
                    case 0:
                        if(type == 0 && item == 0) {
                            sp_name = "cc_left";
                        } else if(type == 0 && item == 1){
                            sp_name = "cc_left1";
                        } else if(type == 0 && item == 2){
                            sp_name = "cc_left2";
                        }else if(type == 0 && item == 3){
                            sp_name = "cc_left3";
                        }else if(type == 0 && item == 4){
                            sp_name = "cc_left4";
                        }else if(type == 0 && item == 5){
                            sp_name = "cc_left5";
                        }else if(type == 0 && item == 6){
                            sp_name = "cc_left6";
                        }else if(type == 1 && item == 0) {
                            sp_name = "ccL_left";
                        } else if(type == 1 && item == 1){
                            sp_name = "ccL_left1";
                        } else if(type == 1 && item == 2){
                            sp_name = "ccL_left2";
                        }else if(type == 1 && item == 3){
                            sp_name = "ccL_left3";
                        }else if(type == 1 && item == 4){
                            sp_name = "ccL_left4";
                        }else if(type == 1 && item == 5){
                            sp_name = "ccL_left5";
                        }else if(type == 1 && item == 6){
                            sp_name = "ccL_left6";
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        if(type == 0 && item == 0) {
                            sp_name = "cc_right";
                        } else if(type == 0 && item == 1){
                            sp_name = "cc_right1";
                        } else if(type == 0 && item == 2){
                            sp_name = "cc_right2";
                        }else if(type == 0 && item == 3){
                            sp_name = "cc_right3";
                        }else if(type == 0 && item == 4){
                            sp_name = "cc_right4";
                        }else if(type == 0 && item == 5){
                            sp_name = "cc_right5";
                        }else if(type == 0 && item == 6){
                            sp_name = "cc_right6";
                        }else if(type == 1 && item == 0) {
                            sp_name = "ccL_right";
                        } else if(type == 1 && item == 1){
                            sp_name = "ccL_right1";
                        } else if(type == 1 && item == 2){
                            sp_name = "ccL_right2";
                        }else if(type == 1 && item == 3){
                            sp_name = "ccL_right3";
                        }else if(type == 1 && item == 4){
                            sp_name = "ccL_right4";
                        }else if(type == 1 && item == 5){
                            sp_name = "ccL_right5";
                        }else if(type == 1 && item == 6){
                            sp_name = "ccL_right6";
                        }
                        break;
                        default:
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"ERR 208",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.cck_spinner:

                switch (pos) {
                    case 0:
                        if (type == 0 && position == 0) {
                            sp_name = "cc_left";
                        } else if (type == 0 && position == 1) {
                            sp_name = "cc_right";
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You can't change LABEL of this key", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        if (type == 0 && position == 0) {
                            sp_name = "cc_left1";
                        } else if (type == 0 && position == 1) {
                            sp_name = "cc_right1";
                        } else if (type == 1 && position == 0) {
                            sp_name = "ccL_left1";
                        } else if (type == 1 && position == 1) {
                            sp_name = "ccL_right1";
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if (type == 0 && position == 0) {
                            sp_name = "cc_left2";
                        } else if (type == 0 && position == 1) {
                            sp_name = "cc_right2";
                        } else if (type == 1 && position == 0) {
                            sp_name = "ccL_left2";
                        } else if (type == 1 && position == 1) {
                            sp_name = "ccL_right2";
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        if (type == 0 && position == 0) {
                            sp_name = "cc_left3";
                        } else if (type == 0 && position == 1) {
                            sp_name = "cc_right3";
                        } else if (type == 1 && position == 0) {
                            sp_name = "ccL_left3";
                        } else if (type == 1 && position == 1) {
                            sp_name = "ccL_right3";
                        }
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        if (type == 0 && position == 0) {
                            sp_name = "cc_left4";
                        } else if (type == 0 && position == 1) {
                            sp_name = "cc_right4";
                        } else if (type == 1 && position == 0) {
                            sp_name = "ccL_left4";
                        } else if (type == 1 && position == 1) {
                            sp_name = "ccL_right4";
                        }
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        if (type == 0 && position == 0) {
                            sp_name = "cc_left5";
                        } else if (type == 0 && position == 1) {
                            sp_name = "cc_right5";
                        } else if (type == 1 && position == 0) {
                            sp_name = "ccL_left5";
                        } else if (type == 1 && position == 1) {
                            sp_name = "ccL_right5";
                        }
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        if (type == 0 && position == 0) {
                            sp_name = "cc_left6";
                        } else if (type == 0 && position == 1) {
                            sp_name = "cc_right6";
                        } else if (type == 1 && position == 0) {
                            sp_name = "ccL_left6";
                        } else if (type == 1 && position == 1) {
                            sp_name = "ccL_right6";
                        }
                        break;


                    default:
                        if (type == 0 && position == 0) {
                            sp_name = "cc_left";
                        } else if (type == 0 && position == 1) {
                            sp_name = "cc_right";
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You can't change LABEL of this key", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                }
                break;
        }
        pfKey4.setHint(sp.getString(sp_name, "not_found"));

    }
```

Comment: if your code works, code review may be a better place to ask this type of question

Comment: can you describe in better detail what you are trying to accomplish exactly

Comment: Those if-else statements seem pretty identical in each case. Why not just move them to a method and then call it? Again, this is more code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems `sp_name` simply changes based on those 3 variables and `adapterView.getId()` which you don't go into. From your code I believe if `position` is 0 then the name has left, or if 1 then right. The number at the end is `item` if greater than 0. And `type` of 0 means it starts with cc_ and `type` 1 means ccL_. I would make a short function to create sp_name.

```
String sp_name="";
// type
if(type==0)
  sp_name="cc_";
else
  sp_name="ccL_";
//position
if(pos==0)
  sp_name+="left";
else
  sp_name+="right";
//item
if(item>0)
  sp_name+=(item+"");
return sp_name;
```

Comment: The Integer.toString is redundant.

Comment: `sp_name += (item + "")` ?

Answer (score 1):

Like @deperm's answer but shorter.

```
return (type == 0 ? "cc_" : "ccL_") +
       (pos == 0 ? "left" : "right") +
       (item > 0 ? "" + item : "");
```